# PTransform passing additional PCollection as side input

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to implement a composite PTransform in my pipeline. I have a main input PCollection and an additional PCollection which I need to pass to my PTransform so that it can be used within my composite transform ParDo's as side inputs. Is it possible to pass through composite PTransform constructor or do I need use different approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a PCollectionView through the constructor. For example: [Access elements of PCollectionView<List<Foo>> : Google Cloud Dataflow/Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061661/access-elements-of-pcollectionviewlistfoo-google-cloud-dataflow-apache-bea)

Comment: Can I pass a PCollectionView through the PTransform constructor (similar to ParDo function)?

Comment: I believe you can.